# Silverlight OOB App Won't Install on OS X

Tags: silverlight, macos, out-of-browser, silverlight-oob

I've built an Out-Of-Browser application using Silverlight, which if right-clicked while running in-browser gives you the "Install BlaBla Application onto this computer" option.

This works just fine on my Windows 7 machine and I get the icon added to my desktop. On my OS X testbox however, **I still get the install option when I right-click on the application, but it doesn't do anything.** I click the option to install and absolutely nothing happens.

What's the deal with that? I've written the app in Silverlight 4, and have the latest version of Silverlight installed on my OS X box. Why won't the app install and run OOB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using Safari on MacOS X, I thought I had the same problem, when in fact, Safari was creating the install 'popup' below itself, so it wasn't visible.